Furnace Intake Clearance
I have a flat Furnace intake grate on the floor and would like to put a piece of furniture over top of it. Whats the height clearance I need overtop?
Specifically hoping to put a diy bookcase overtop it and was going to leave a gap.
If its helps its approximately 26x8 inches

Editing in the size of the return duct under the grate and the dimensions of the toekick area under the proposed bookcase would help you get more definite answers.

There are a few ways to figure out whether a piece of furniture will restrict the air flow too much.
Math:
The idea is to leave the same or more area of opening for air to get into the space under the new furniture as the area of the return duct opening behind the furnace intake grate.
This method is predictive, and doesn't require the actual piece of furniture to be present, but does require a bit of multiplication and visualization.
Measure the area of the return duct, and measure the area of openings under the furniture where air can flow under it to the return duct. The total air flow area under the furniture should be at least equal, but preferably more than, the area of the return duct.
Say, for example, you're going put a low table over the duct:

You wouldn't just measure the edges of the table and the height off the floor to get the air flow area: the air coming from the edges has to constrict to get down to the edges of the return duct. This constriction reduces the effective return area under the furniture. Instead, you'd "project" the return duct mentally up to the underside of the table, like this:

This will give you a closed-top but open-side "box" where the air effectivelly has to go through for it to get into the return duct:

Then each side of the "box" formed by this projection can give you the area to measure:

Note that if the duct is very close to a wall or a part of the furniture that blocks it, like a back or side panel, don't include those projected "sides" of the "box" in the area calculation.
Take the length of each side of the duct that air can come to, multiplied by the height from the floor to the underside of the table, to get the area of that side. Add together all side areas that can admit air, and that number should be at least, and preferably more than, the area of the duct.
An example: The duct is 12 inches square, for an area of 12 x 12 = 144 square inches. The underside of the table is 5 inches above the floor. Each "side" of the airflow to the duct is 12 inches x 5 inches = 60 square inches. The duct is very close to a wall, so that side is ignored. There are three open sides remaining at 60 square inches each, for 180 square inches of effective air flow under the table. 180 > 144, so the table shouldn't restrict the airflow. If the table underside were 4" off the floor, the effective area would also 144 square inches, same as the duct area, so some restriction might start happening.
If your proposed bookcase only covers a portion of the duct, only allow for that covered portion in the mental projection of the duct, and allow for the full open uncovered portion of the duct as free flow in your comparison of areas.
Edit: Your picture shows a return grate surrounded by three walls. My cabinet-maker's eye says the grille is about 6"-ish inches wide. You can measure the depth yourself. Doing the projection thing and keeping in mind that the airflow can only come from the front, you'll want to have the area under the bottom shelf of your bookcase completely open and no closer to the floor than the 6"-ish inches of the grate width. An extra inch or two would be better. You should be able to get full airflow.
Current Meter
If you have the furniture and a clamp-on current meter, you can read the electric current drawn by the furnace when the furniture is moved away from the return duct, and when it is in place. If the furnace electric current changes when the furniture is in place over the return duct, then the furniture is restricting the air flow. A little bit of change is probably ok, but a lot will be bad. You might look at the blower motor's nameplate current to get an idea of the nominal current the motor is expected to draw, and determine "a little" or "a lot" from that nameplate current number. Try setting the furnace to only run the blower, not heat or cool, to reduce other current draws in the furnace that may throw off the current reading.
(Note: the direction of current change is up for determination. Based on web research it depends on the kind of fan in the furnace: even with a squirrel-cage-style blower, the direction of curve of the blades can determine the direction of current change. But a restriction will change the current draw.)
A piece of thread
Tie a light thread to an air register in the room. Turn on the blower, then watch the thread as the air blows out, while the return duct is not restricted. The string will buffet about some, but it should be staying at a steady average level. Place a panel of something over the duct while the furnace is blowing. The string will drop down some.
Now, put the furniture over the return duct. If the string returns to the full higher level when the duct was unrestricted, then the furniture isn't interfering. If some drop in the string happens, then the furniture is restricting the return air. You can rearrange the furniture to get less restriction,
Your ears and hands
This method is very subjective, but can work. The air flow coming out of the registers will change, and the sound may be different, when the return duct is restricted. You can hear and feel this difference simply by placing a panel of something over the duct while the furnace is blowing.
Now, have someone move the furniture onto and away from the return duct, while you listen and feel the air flow in a different room. You could try to do this as a "blind" 'scientific' method, where you record on a list whether you feel and hear restriction each time the furniture is moved, while the other person records on a different list random movements of the furniture, sometimes onto the duct, sometimes off, sometimes moving the furniture without taking it off the duct and sometimes moving it around in the room away from the duct. Carefully comparing the two lists should show if the furniture restricts the air flow to the duct.

Fan motor current consumption will actually decrease if the intake is restricted - less air being moved = less work being done = less power consumption. Of course if there’s more than one grate on the intake duct, blocking one may not change the total airflow through the fan, just reduce the air circulation in that room.

Interesting point, @nobody. I have seen a regular box fan increase current draw when it is restricted. A squirrel cage blower could act different. Will do some more research. Meanwhile will edit to say the current may change for now.

Thank for this detailed response!
I did add a photo. Its sort Of got 3 walls around itbut the one “wall” is tiny

Thanks for the picture @HayleyFox . I edited in an idea at the end of the "Math" section on what you could do with the bookcase.

Thank you! For all your help!
I appreciate everything you’ve helped with!
